# Nginx rewrite server name rule

Tags: nginx, rewrite

If I want to do a rewite rule on nginx : 
Visit http://*1.abc.com   
* = any single character  
will 301 redirect  http//*9.abc.com   
so I created the following config :

```
server {
   listen 80 ;
   server_name ~^(.+?)1\.abc\.com$;
   rewrite ^/(.*) http://$19.abc.com permanent;
}
```

The URL will rewrite to : http//9.abc.com 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a numeric capture in the `server_name` statement and a numeric capture in the `rewrite` statement.

The variable `$1` in the `rewrite` statement represents the value of the numeric capture from the regular expression in the same `rewrite` statement.

It is always the case that numeric captures are overwritten by the **last** regular expression to be evaluated.

You can use named captures where one or more regular expressions may be evaluated between the capture and where the value is evaluated. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

For example:

```
server_name ~^(?<prefix>.+?)1\.example\.com$;
rewrite ^ "http://${prefix}9.example.com" permanent;
```

Or, you can avoid any intervening regular expressions by using a `return` statement, for example:

```
server_name ~^(.+?)1\.example\.com$;
return 301 "http://${1}9.example.com$is_args$args";
```

I prefer to use `${1}` rather than `$1` where the intent may be ambiguous. In which case the expressions will also need to be quoted. *The `$is_args$args` appends the optional query string, which matches the behaviour of the original `rewrite` statement.*